# Adding backbone event dynmically after page load not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to add an event dynamically but the event doesn't fire. jQuery is not available.

Backbone Code

```
var OptimizelyTeacherClick = Backbone.View.extend({

events: {
    "click button.start-class-creation" : "optimizelyEvent"
},

optimizelyEvent: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Optimizely Event');
    alert('Optimizely Event');
    }

});

var optimizelyTeacherClick = new OptimizelyTeacherClick({ el: $('.start-class-creation') }).render();
```

HTML

```
<form class="start-class-creation-form" action="http://site.dev/classes/online/new?type=online&amp;via=teach&amp;button=page_top" method="post">
<input value="My Class" name="title" class="initialized" type="hidden">
<button type="submit" class="btn submit-btn large primary start-class-creation">Get Started</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [root `el` element](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) for the `OptimizelyTeacherClick` view is the button itself. So the event key string should just be `click`. Events are bound on the `el`.

```
var OptimizelyTeacherClick = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click": "optimizelyEvent"
    },

    optimizelyEvent: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Optimizely Event');
    }
});
```

You could also just instantiate the view with the selector string, Backbone will fetch it with jQuery.

```
var optimizelyTeacherClick = new OptimizelyTeacherClick({
    el: '.start-class-creation'
}).render();
```

---

That being said, I don't feel like you're going in the right direction with this design, but I don't know enough on your project to help more.